# how to fix a fact that the recipient received the file so that the recipient could not dispute it?

Tags: contract-development, blockchain, contract-design

how to fix a fact that the recipient received the file so that the recipient could not dispute it? How to do this by a smart contract?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to ask the recipient to confirm if they have received a file.

Then you write this confirmation in the blockchain.

Identity recipients by their Ethereum address. You can use Soldity smart contracts to have the recipient to make a transaction where they confirm they have received the file.